# Process doesn't return it's output

Tags: java, process, io, applescript

I wrote a simple AppleScript and I am trying to call the process from Java that would use the `osascript` to run the actual script. The script seems to be executed, but it doesn't output anything. I tried to run the same script from Terminal, and it worked as expected - I got the output like `{{300, 450}, {500, 500}}`.

```
    public void macTest() throws ScriptException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        final String script= "tell application \"System Events\" to tell application process \"Eclipse\"\n" + 
                "   get {size, position} of window 1\n" + 
                "end tell";

        System.out.println(runProcess(String.format("osascript -e '%s'", script)));
    }

    public static String runProcess(String cmdline) throws IOException, 
    InterruptedException { 
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdline); 
        p.waitFor(); 
        try { 
            return readContents(p.getInputStream()); 
        } finally { 
            p.destroy(); 
        } 
    } 

    public static String readContents(InputStream inputStream) 
            throws IOException { 
        StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder(); 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
                inputStream)); 
        try { 
            String line; 
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                contents.append(line).append("\n"); 
            } 
        } finally { 
            reader.close(); 
        } 
        return contents.toString().trim(); 
    }
```

It seems like the input stream is empty here. How do I get the output of my process in Java?

Comment: What's in `p.getErrorStream()`?  Look there.

Comment: One tip would be to try the one-line version of your AppleScript, which would look like this: `"tell application \"System Events\" to tell application process \"Eclipse\" to get {size, position} of window 1"` (no `end tell` needed).

Answer (score 0):

Calling system processes from Java may be a little tricky: Realize that an implicit multithreading is running under:

- In one hand, you have your java program running on a JVM (one process).
- On the other hand, there is the subprocess you launched, which is running independently of the JVM. This process is surely writing data to its output stream and/or its error stream (and maybe even reading data from its input stream, but this does not seem the case).

In brief: You must start a thread to read the subprocess' output stream (through your `readContents`method) and another to read the subprocess' error stream. And, once they are started, you may invoke the `waitFor` method to block the main thread until the subprocess ends.